# Android never ShutDown App - Unwanted Behaviour

Tags: android, shutdown

I know how Android works concerning killing not needed processes if the memory is needed by another app, bu I dont like the following behaviour of the App I develop at the moment:

- I start my App, which has a lot of different screens/activities
- After using it, i push the Home Button of my phone and switch to some other App.
  (Lets say I did this while Activity C on Screen C was active).

My phone is a HTC One X, I checked, that there are always about 300MB of Memory available, when I run the Apps I usually need.

The Problem:
Even if I restart the App after a couple of days without using it, the App restarts with Activity C on screen C. In my opinion, after some days of not using the App, it should restart with the "Welcome Screen" i created.

As there are no Backgroundprocesses or ressources used (all these stuff is done by pushing buttons and has to be finished - so no automated backgroundprocesses are needed), I think, Android does not feel the need to kill it.

Does anybody know, how the "Android Best Practice" looks like for this or where I can read what behaviour the App should have in this case?

(... I am not looking for Code, but I dont know what way I should go to solve this)

Many Thanks for any help

Comment: Just use onResume(), which will be called when your app returns to the foreground, to set it up however you want. The key point is that you cannot assume whether Android will or will not destroy your activity and using onCreate(), onResume() and onStart() correctly gives you complete control over what shows when.  If you want the welcome screen to show, then in activity C onResume(), start the welcome activity and finish activity C. However, this is not how users expect apps to work. I expect that if I use another app, then go back to to previous one, then it will resume where I left it.

Comment: First thnx for your answer! I am not sure about that! Do you expect this also if there are a couple of days between close and restart??

Comment: Android could destroy your activity immediately after onPause(), it might destroy it 2 weeks later, or it might never destroy it.  The point is you should not assume, you should always handle the life cycle.

Comment: So, if you were a user, what about this sollution: I save the Date of onPause(), and calculate the time span in onResume(). If the time span ist over 48hours, than go back to welcome screen, else, stay in resumed activity. Would this be ok for you as user?

Comment: If it made sense :)  They are your users and your usage scenarios.  Only you know if it makes sense to show the welcome screen after 2 days away!  If it does, then your approach is fine.  Good luck.

Comment: Thnx! Will do so! Unfortunately I cant vote for a comment or mark it as answer! If u write one, I will mark it as answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily do `finish()` the activity's on `onPause()` method.

Not sure whether this is a best practice. Awaiting other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, the following flag can help you when used by an `Intent` starting a new `Activity`: [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY). As the documentation says:

> f set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished.

So if all your `Activities`, except of the welcome screen, are started using this flag, next time a user comes back to your app he arrives at the welcome screen. The drawback of this solution is that if a user receives a call while working with your application, he will also be transfered to welcome screen when the call is finished. Don't know if there is any other solution. Hope this helps.